# Using VBA instead of using formula (INDEX & MATCH) in every cells Excel

Tags: vba, excel

As you can see on the "Data" sheet, I have data table like this (Pls see below)

[image: Data Sheet]

The Output that I want to be is like this :

[image: Output Sheet]

Currently in the Output sheet,

1. I have to manually add-in YYYYMM each column for every month
2. For each month of the column, I have to put formula to get the Order Qty.
   formula is like this:

   ```
   =IFNA(INDEX(Data!C:C,(MATCH(A3&$B$2,Data!D:D,0))),"")
   ```

The code can give me the Order Qty of each month.

However, what I wanted to do is generate monthly and get the Order Qty by using **VBA**.

Comment: What version of Excel? Can't you use SUMIFS?

Comment: @pnuts I know PivotTable can solve it but I want to do it in VBA because this is just a sub program that I am trying to code.

Comment: @Alan, we do not need to use SUMIF

Comment: You can either use worksheetfunction in VBA. For eg. Application.WorksheetFunction.Index or apply a formula in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample that uses a variant Array to collect the results, so will be Fast.

Assumes you have pre-built your Results Table Item and Number headers

```
Sub Demo()
    'Call FillTable with parameters
    ' Top Left Cell of Source Data range, including headers
    ' Top Left Cell of Destination Table range, including headers
    ' Column to match in Source
    ' Column to return from Source
    FillTable Worksheets("Data").Range("A1"), Worksheets("Final").Range("A2"), 4, 3
End Sub

Sub FillTable(rSrc As Range, rTable As Range, MatchCol As Long, QtyCol As Long)
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vTable As Variant
    Dim Items As Variant, Dates As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long


    Set rSrc = Range(rSrc.Offset(1, 0), rSrc.End(xlDown)).Resize(, Application.Max(MatchCol, QtyCol))
    Set rTable = Range(rTable.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0), rTable.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))

    vSrc = rSrc.Value2
    vTable = rTable.Value2

    Items = rTable.Columns(0).Value2
    Dates = rTable.Rows(0).Value2

    For cl = 1 To UBound(vTable, 2)
    For rw = 1 To UBound(vTable, 1)
        With Application
            vTable(rw, cl) = .IfNa(.Index(rSrc.Columns(QtyCol), .Match(Items(rw, 1) & Dates(1, cl), rSrc.Columns(MatchCol), 0)), vbNullString)
        End With
    Next rw, cl

    rTable = vTable
End Sub
```

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thanks for your expertise advise and coding.

Comment: ....the current Output is start from Column B. if I want to start from Column H, how can I modify the code? Please advise.

Comment: @java404 change the range(s) you call `FillTable` with to refer to the cells I defined in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FillData()

For Each cell In Worksheets("Data").Columns(2).Cells

    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub    'stop program if no value
    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(cell.Value) = True Then GoTo line1  'do not perform action if YYYYMM

    Set FindMth = Worksheets("Final").Rows(2).Find(cell.Value)  'Find Month at Final Sheet
    Set FindItem = Worksheets("Final").Columns(1).Find(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)   'Find Item Number at Final Sheet

    If Not FindMth Is Nothing Then
        C = FindMth.Column  'Column Month
    Else        
        If Worksheets("Final").Range("B2").Value <> "" Then
            Worksheets("Final").Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
            C = Worksheets("Final").Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column   'Column Month if B2 not empty
        Else
            Worksheets("Final").Range("B2").Value = cell.Value
            C = 2
        End If
    End If

    If Not FindItem Is Nothing Then
        R = FindItem.Row    'Row Item Number
    Else
        Worksheets("Final").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        R = Worksheets("Final").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    End If

    Worksheets("Final").Cells(R, C).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'Assign Order Qty
    Worksheets("Final").Range("B1:" & Cells(1, C).Address).Merge    'Merge YYYYMM cell

line1:
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The program can auto fill new YYYYMM and Item No.

Comment: thanks for your advise. I alr found the solution that given by @Chris